# Do I have to use a constructor when importing an external module I made in React?

Tags: reactjs

I made a module in react.
So, I imported the module. And then, the function of the external module was called using the constructor.

```
import { connect } from './api';
...

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  connect(message => {
  console.log(message);
  });
 }

 render(){
  ...
 }  
}
```

**But** I would like to express class fields syntax without using a constructor.

```
import { connect } from './api';
...

class App extends Component {

  connect(message => {
  console.log(message);
  });

  render(){
   ...
  }
}
```

The results of the above code, 'connect' function is not executed because 'connect' is not declared.

Can't I get an function of external module  without a constructor?

Comment: Give a look to the React life cycle component

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_component_life_cycle.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your connect.js:

```
export const connect = message => {
  console.log(message);
};
```

Here is your component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { connect } from './connect';

class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    connect('connected');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Some Text...</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Should be fairly clear... If you have a question ask...